# Fallo en Connection a traves de JNDI

Tags: java, base-de-datos, spring, tomcat

Corriendo bajo un Tomcat 9 y JDK 1.8, usando Spring 5, estoy intentando configurar una conexión JNDI para usar un DataSource.

Si configuro Spring, a traves de XML, consigo mi DataSource y todo parece funcionar bien. El DataSource lo configuro en mi applicationContext.xml, de esta manera:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/yages"
        resource-ref="true"/>
```

Si uso la clase AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer para inicializar Spring, mi DataSource se crea pero al intentar coger la conexión me da el siguiente error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2049)
```

El DataSource lo intento crear con esta función:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
  public DataSource dataSource(Environment env)  throws NamingException
  {
        DataSource datasource=null;
        try {
            JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            datasource= lookup.getDataSource("jdbc/yages");
            datasource.getConnection();
            System.out.println("\n\n!!Cogida la Conexion del DataSource correctamente!!");
            return datasource;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("\n\n!!Error al coger la Conexion del DataSource!!\n\n");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return datasource;
  }
```

Parece que el DataSource lo coge bien, pero la conexión a la base de datos esta cerrada. Sin embargo si uso el DataSource, configurado a traves de XML si que me funciona bien, por lo que presupongo, que no es un problema ni de la conexion a la base de datos ni de la configuración de Tomcat.

¿ Alguna idea de porque se me cierra la conexión ?.

Gracias.

Comment: Por lo que veo, si reinicio Tomcat si que funciona la conexion. Pero en el momento que le hago un nuevo deploy de la aplicación vuelve a cerrarme la conexion.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado el problema. 
Spring cuando hace un undeploy, por defecto destruye los objetos. En este caso al destruir el DataSource, a este le cierra la conexión a la base de datos y a la siguiente vez, ya no funciona.
La solucion es crear el Bean con esta orden:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource", destroyMethod = "")
```

De esta manera Spring no destruye el Bean y todo funciona correctamente.